# Kings Tour Python

Tags: python, graph

This is a depth-first search Kings Tour. I call it like this because the king must pass by all coordinates only touching them once (like a knights tour).
How could I improve?
Thank You

```
    # author @reivaJ

from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product
import sys
import numpy as np
from random import choice
from operator import itemgetter

sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
class BoardGraph(object):
    '''Square room graph, connecting continous tile spaces'''

    def __init__(self, height, width): 
        '''creates a graph for a square room of dimension height x width''' 
        self.width = width
        self.height = height  
        self.nodes =  list(product(range(height), range(width)))
        self.edges = defaultdict(dict)
        self.breed()

    def breed(self):
        for node in self.nodes:
            for children in self.nodes:
                if children != node and abs(node[0] - children[0]) <=1 and abs(node[1] - children[1]) <=1:
                    self.edges[node][children] = 0


    def cornerWeight(self, child, corner):
        value = abs(child[0]-corner[0]) + abs(child[1] - corner[1])
        return value
    
    def getCorner(self, node):
        corners = [(0,0), (0, self.width - 1), (self.height-1, 0), (self.height-1, self.width-1)]
        for corner in corners:
            if abs(corner[0] - node[0]) < self.height/2 and abs(corner[1] - node[1]) < self.width/2:
                return corner 
        
    def updateWeight(self, node, path):
        corner = self.getCorner(node)
        for children in self.childrenOf(node):
            available_children = 0
            for child in self.childrenOf(children):                
                if child not in path:
                    available_children += 1
            available_children += self.cornerWeight(children, corner)
            self.edges[node][children] = available_children 

    def childrenOf(self, node):
       
        children = sorted(self.edges[node].items(), key = itemgetter(1))
        return[child[0] for child in children]

    def getEdges(self):
        return self.edges.keys()

    def printGraph(self):
        for node, children in self.edges.items():
            print ("Node:", node, "     Children:", children)


class PathFinder(object):

    def __init__(self, height, width, start):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.graph = BoardGraph(height, width)
        if start not in self.graph.getEdges():
            raise ValueError ('Start possition must be within graph.')
        self.start = start
        self.path = self.goDeep(start)

    def get_start(self):
        return self.start
    
    def get_graph(self):
        return self.graph
    
    def get_path(self):
        return self.path

    def goDeep(self, start, path=[]): 
        node = start
        path.append(node)   
        if all(node in path for node in self.graph.getEdges()):
            return path    
        self.graph.updateWeight(node, path)
        for n in self.graph.childrenOf(node):
            if n not in path:
                new_path = self.goDeep(n, path)
                if new_path != None:
                    return path
        if len(path) != 1:
            path.remove(node)


    def representSolution(self):
        model = np.zeros((self.height, self.width), dtype = int)
        step = 1
        for coordinate in self.path:
            model[coordinate] = step
            step += 1
        print(model)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    height = 10
    width = 10
    start = choice(list(product(range(height), range(width)))) 
    p = PathFinder(height, width, start)
    p.representSolution()
```

Comment: you can also see it here

Comment: https://github.com/reivak720/kingsTour.git

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good and seems to be working fine which is a great starting point!
Let's try to see how things can be improved somehow.

**Style**

Python has a style guide called https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ which is an interesting read. You may not follow it blindly but it is a good starting point to follow a few common conventions. For instance, method names usually use `snake_case`. (I'll come back to names later)

**Rewriting `breed` with itertools**

It looks like you know a bit about `itertools` as you've used `product`.
The double loop in in `breed` could be written with `product` as well but it is a good reason to try the other tools in the box.

Indeed, as we do not want the pairs where `children` and `node` are the same, one could rely on `permutations` instead:

```
    for (node, children) in itertools.permutations(self.nodes, 2):
        if abs(node[0] - children[0]) <= 1 and abs(node[1] - children[1]) <= 1:
            self.edges[node][children] = 0
```

but one could also use `combinations` and iterate over half as many pairs:

```
    for (n1, n2) in itertools.combinations(self.nodes, 2):
        if abs(n1[0] - n2[0]) <= 1 and abs(n1[1] - n2[1]) <= 1:
            self.edges[n1][n2] = 0
            self.edges[n2][n1] = 0
```

**Renaming `cornerWeight`**

`cornerWeight` looks a bit an obscure as a name. It actually corresponds to a pretty generic concept of distance. I've renamed it:

```
def dist_l1_norm(self, m, n):
    '''Distance using norm l1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry .'''
    return abs(m[0] - n[0]) + abs(m[1] - n[1])
```

**Simplify `getCorner`**

`get_corner` iterates over 4 point candidates to find the closest one based on some coordinate checks. This can actually be used to generate the `x` and the `y` without going through multiple points:

```
def get_closest_corner(self, node):
    '''
    get the closest corner to a node
    '''
    x = 0 if node[0] < self.height/2 else self.height-1
    y = 0 if node[1] < self.width/2 else self.width-1
    return (x, y)
```

(I took this chance to rename it)

**Making `update_weight` more concise**

Warning: This may not be an advice applicable here as it can make things harder to understand but it is a probably a good thing to know anyway: instead of using many calls to `+=`, you can use the builtin `sum` over an iterable. Once applied, one can see that the variable `available_children` is not really required (except maybe for readibility purposes).

You'd get:

```
    corner = self.get_closest_corner(node)
    for children in self.childrenOf(node):
        self.edges[node][children] = \
            self.dist_l1_norm(children, corner) + \
            sum(child not in path for child in self.childrenOf(children))
```

(but again, here it may be better not to use this if you think it makes things harder to read)

**Improving `goDeep`**

The `goDeep` method seems to be where the magic happens. Let's try to see how it can be improved.

The name does not convey much meaning, I'd suggest `depth_first_search` but I would not be surprised if you could come up with something better.

Having some recursive function that modifies the object passed as an argument can be a nice recipe to have impossible to debug behavior. My suggestion would be to keep the list `path` unchanged, for instand by copying it instead of updating it. Performing a bit of small changes to make sure things work, we'd have:

```
def depth_first_search(self, start, starting_path=[]):
    '''
    recursive depth-first search
    '''
    path = starting_path + [start]
    if all(node in path for node in self.graph.getNodes()):
        return path
    self.graph.update_weight(start, path)
    for n in self.graph.childrenOf(start):
        if n not in path:
            new_path = self.depth_first_search(n, path)
            if new_path != None:
                return new_path
    return None
```

---

I'll stop here as I am running out of things I can easily improve as I do not know much about the problem solved.

Comment: Oh you can keep going if you have more.

Comment: This is  great. Thank You.

Comment: There is really no original problem, we studied breath first and depth first but did no exercises, so I decided this was a good practice for mounting on my roomba, make it navigate threw every tile only touching it once. I needed a path finder, and this is my practice. It does tend to go to corners and abandoned places first, and tends to fiind the path in a 900 coordinate room.

Comment: You can do that with sum? awesome. Real great advice. Thank you

Comment: rubber ducky told be about that norm

Comment: now i know its name